# Import from a package with known import failure

Tags: python, distutils

What I want to achieve is as follows:

I have a python package, let's call it `foo`, comprising a directory `foo` containing an `__init__.py` and, under normal use a compiled extension library (either a `.so` or a `.pyd` file), which `__init__.py` imports into the top level namespace.

Now, the problem is that I wish the top level namespace to contain a version string which is available to `setup.py` during building and packaging, when the extension library is not necessarily available (not yet built), and so would cause an `ImportError` when trying to import `foo.version`.

Now, clearly, I could have an exception handler in `__init__.py` that just ignores failures in importing anything, but this is not ideal as there may be a real reason that the user cares about why the package can't be imported.

Is there some way I can have the version string in a single place in the package, have it importable, yet not break the exceptions from attempts to import the extension?

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to do… but why not just move the version string from `__init.py__` to a new file `version.py`, and `import foo.version` in your setup? Or, maybe even more simply, instead of munging `sys.path` so you can `import foo` in `setup.py`, just munge `sys.path` so you can `import version` as a top-level module.

Comment: why would I be munging `sys.path`? By top level, I mean top level wrt the package (so in the `foo` namespace). Also, importing anything from `foo` necessarily runs `__init__.py`, so a separate `version.py` would not be adequate.

Comment: You haven't installed the package yet, so where are you importing it from? Presumably it's `.` or `./src`, or `dirname(__file__)` or `join(dirname(__file__), 'src')`, or something like that.

Comment: From the directory containing `foo`. Generally one runs the `distutils` `setup.py` from such a location. It might be possible to do some path fiddling to just load a single module without triggering the whole package to load.

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on the package being in the shell's current working directory, and the current working directory being in `sys.path`. In fact, you usually shouldn't be trying to import the code you're trying to set up and build, but if you look at some packages that do this, almost all of them use an explicit path to do so. If you have good reasons to violate those two norms, I don't think munging `sys.path`, or using `importlib`/`imp` instead of just `import`, should be considered beyond the pale.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Fortunately, `setup.py` generally has a well defined location and is run in isolation. I think it's reasonable to put a mild hack in there to maintain package sanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As opposed to ignoring failures when importing print out a trace message or a warning so that the user will still get the negative feedback.

As for importing a specific subfile if you are using python 3.3+ (or python 2.7) you can use imp.load_source which accepts a pathname of a file you want to import.

Comment: Yeah, I think this might be the way to go. `imp.load_source` is part of python 2.7. I'll have a play tomorrow...

Comment: I agree. Don't try to hack up the package so it works in different ways in different cases; just move the version into `version.py` and access that directly.

Comment: Just to be clear, the above answer regarding `imp.load_source` works just fine in python 2.7.